# how to autoclick this `button`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button data-ratparam="all" data-ratid="fixed_checkout" data-ratevent="pv,appear" class="cart-button checkout new-cart-button"><span class="normal"></span></button>
```

here is the element I cut from chrome
I am new to web dev and I  wonder if this is a button at all ?

I wanna auto click this button and used event visual but nothing appeared on the web .
Don't know what to do .

many thanks

Comment: What did you do to try to autoclick it?

Comment: What? Explained better

Comment: @epascarello it's a 'buy' button , but I didn't debug it out

Comment: @Ian Gallegos I wanna auto click this button . but cannot debug out the desired `info` . I used getElementByClassName(it'sClassName).click() , but got a error saying no `click`  But it is a button . every button has a click yes ?

Comment: you can use setInterval jquery function

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about your specific button, but you can easily use JQuery's click() method to trigger it's onClick callback.

Just like that: `$( "p" ).click();`

Comment: I used getElementByClassName(it'sClassName).click() , but got a error saying no click But it is a button . every button has a click yes ?

Comment: and your code how do I implement it ? and 'p' stands for my button's className or ?

Comment: You could add an id to your button:

<button id="mybtn"/>

And use it like this: $( "#mybtn" ).click();

Comment: I dont own this web . possible to add id to button ?

Comment: i got this info `[document, context: document]` not no more .dont know what to do

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like a non-jquery solution then the code you originally attempted isn't too far off.

getElementsByClassName("className") returns an array of all elements with that class type. You must index the array to obtain the specific element that you want to call click() on. I believe what you're looking for is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cart-button checkout new-cart-button")[0].click();
```

Tested and working on my end in the Chrome browser.

Comment: I put it on snippet but got error  ``  at <anonymous>:1:1
    at list-3.4.5.3.js:42```

Comment: @Chris .click() does trigger a click.

Comment: @iDelusion maybe a link to the website you're trying this on might help?

Comment: here is the link http://item.rakuten.co.jp/modescape/1-240002031967/ I just wanna auto click that `buy button` it's icon is a Cart and named 'ご購入手続きへ'